# ArrayAdapter - Split 2 strings

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

**[SOLVED]**
I need a small help here.
I have an ArrayAdapter which contains 2 strings, I want to show user 1st part of the ArrayAdapter and when the users clicks on a particular item i want to get the ID of that specific item and post it.
In the below image as you can see i wamt to show JAVA to user and want to send JAVAs ID when users click on button.

[image]

Code:

```
 private class getSkillsList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private String dataFetchedFromURL = "";

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... skillListURL) {

        try {
            String newUrl = skillListURL[0];
            URL url = new URL(newUrl);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while (line != null) {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                dataFetchedFromURL = dataFetchedFromURL + line;
            }
            System.out.print("DATA: " + dataFetchedFromURL);
            JSONArray root = new JSONArray(dataFetchedFromURL);
            skillList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < root.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObjectHoldingCountries = root.getJSONObject(i);
HashMap<String, Integer> skillsMap = new HashMap<>();                   
skillsMap.put(jsonObjectHoldingCountries.optString("lookupValue"), jsonObjectHoldingCountries.getInt("lookupValueId"));
            }
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        for(int i=0; i<skillsMap.size();i++){
            skillList.add(String.valueOf(skillsMap.get(i)));
        }
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Skills.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, skillList);
        acSkillTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

## 1 UPDATE:

Now i have updated my code and storing the JSON response in HashMap with first key is String and Value is Integer.
And when i tried to add those Hashmap in adapter in post execute method it shows NULL in autocompletetext dropdown.

## 2 UPDATE:

I got my solution, I first inserted all my received data into a HashMap and then from hashmap i inserted key value into an array and displayed that array in dropdown using adapter. Cheers! Thanks guys :)

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @NabinBhandari Added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try hashmap with name and id and array with just name . according to position you can get your your id from hashmap.

let me explain you .

```
 hashmap.put("java","350");
 hashmap.put("c++","351");
```

now make an array of data

```
array.add("java");
array.add("c++");
```

now on selecting position no 1 , you can get respective id.

Comment: I am getting this data from APIs JSON response.

Comment: no problem . its fine . you can make Hashmap on successful receiving of data response. and set array  adapter after it

Comment: OK thanks i will try.

Comment: yeah , you can accept this answer also . :) happy coding

Comment: Hey @Tej, I tried using this logic but it is showing NULL in in autocompletetetxview dropdown. Please check my code i have updated my question.

Comment: please sout both . your hashmap and Your array .  which one is empty ,please check

Comment: HashMap is not null. How to add key of hashmap to arraylist? I am doing it like this for(int i=0; i<skillsMap.size();i++) {  skillList.add(String.valueOf(skillsMap.get(i)));  }

Comment: fill your array  exact below your hashmap  like this ..

array.add(jsonObjectHoldingCountries.optString("lookupValue"))